# Работает в Думе государственной. Прописная буква?

Tags: прописная-строчная

> Сказал, что работал в Комитете следственном и в Думе государственной.

Государственная дума и Следственный комитет пишутся с прописных букв. Если слова в названиях поменять местами, то второе слово, писавшееся со строчной буквы, став первым, уже будет писаться с прописной, а первое, писавшееся с прописной буквы, став вторым, будет писаться со строчной буквы?

Comment: С какой целью в ином порядке ставить слова в названиях учреждений? Ещё и дважды.

Comment: Всё в жизни бывает. В бытовой речи кто-то взял и переставил. Я сама слышала, как сказано было именно так, как у меня написано. И ещё, допустим, в интервью кто-то сказал именно так. Надо же записать именно так, как было сказано, без искажения источника!

Comment: Тогда ставьте слова в кавычки как цитированные. И оба со строчной.

Comment: На основании какого правила обе буквы строчными должны быть?

Comment: Цитата перестановкой слов нарушает и смену начальной заглавной на строчную. А второе слово заглавную сохранить не должно по определению. Круг замкнулся: только строчные, только в кавычках и, до кучи, ещё курсивом их дать.

Comment: Может, кто-то даст полноценный ответ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оба слова - со строчной, потому что это разговорное употребление официального названия (контекста я не вижу, но похоже на то). Буквальные правила об этом в справочниках по правописанию мне неизвестны. Но можно отыскать иные обоснования.

В основном названия представляют собой синтаксически неделимые сочетания: Садовое кольцо, Русский музей, Черное море, Полярная звезда, Дворцовая площадь, Куликовская битва, Вербное воскресенье, Нобелевская премия, Бермудский треугольник, венерин башмачок. Их нельзя разрывать - Садовое отремонтированное кольцо или венерин красивый башмачок и т. п. Инверсия тоже разрушает привычное сочетание.

Тем не менее, случаи инверсии встречаются (хотя и редко, что можно проверить по [Национальному корпусу РЯ](https://ruscorpora.ru/)). Но инверсия в русском - стилистический инструмент и неизбежно создает акцент**: либо поэтический, фольклорный, пафосно-риторический, либо разговорный, часто с иронией.

В первом значении прописная буква обычно сохраняется, новая не добавляется (Полярная звезда - звезда Полярная).

> Чтобы наши Стожары ярче всех светили… как вот Большая Медведица или
> звезда Полярная. [А. И. Мусатов. Стожары (1948)]

> Мне все равно теперь. Клубится Енисей. / Звезда Полярная сияет. / И синий блеск возлюбленных очей / Последний ужас застилает. [А. Ахматова. К смерти (1939)]

Во втором - прописная буква не сохраняется. (Хотя мы можем говорить об этой тенденции очень приблизительно - разговорная речь многие годы не фиксировалась на письме. Соответственно, и в правилах орфографии не нуждалась, и посмотреть на нее негде. Письменная разговорная речь возникла недавно, благодаря интернету и мобильной связи. Пока живет без официальных правил.)

> ... Но повидать его и дозвониться ему нет никакой возможности ― в
> гостинице «Звезда» (по температуре ― звезда полярная!) ему не сидится,
> а до остальных мест пребывания ― никак не доберешься. [А. С. Эфрон.
> Письма Б. Л. Пастернаку (1948-1959)]

** Иногда инверсия не создает эмоционального контекста - так случилось с географическими названиями. На это, вероятно, повлияла картография и лексика военного времени. Допускается не только инверсия, но и несогласованность падежа: п-в Кольский, на острове Русский.